# Logstash regex pattern issue

Tags: ruby, regex, logstash, logstash-grok, oniguruma

I have sample plain text:

```
..done, Total time: 10, Errors: 5, there is some text here Results:, , Total time: 10, Errors: 5, , [INFO]...
```

I am trying to parse values of `Total time` and `Errors` fields in Logstash `grok` filter with the following pattern:

```
grok {
  match => {"message" => ".*Total\stime\:\s(?<time>\d*).*Errors\:\s(?<errors>\d*)"}
}
```

But it assigns two values to every field:

> Total time 10, 10
>
> Errors 5, 5;

Is there any way to parse the values of those fields correctly, with one value only?

Comment: I remember someone having similar issue. Check that 1) your input is on 1 single line and `Total time` and `Errors:` only appear once (else, try replacing `.*` with `[\s\S]` or `[\\s\\S]`, not sure about the number of backslashes), 2) try deleting the existing pipeline in elasticsearch and retry. I'd also use `.*Total\s+time:\s*(?<time>\d+).*Errors:\s*(?<errors>\d+)` pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I tried this pattern `.*Total\s+time:\s*(?<time>\d+).*Errors:\s*(?<errors>\d+)` but it again created two values. I also tried `[\s\S]Total\s+time:\s*(?<time>\d+).[\s\S]Errors:\s*(?<errors>\d+)` and it failed, though it passed on https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I actuall meant `[\s\S]*`, not `[\s\S]`.However, I believe there is some issue with the pipeline or the input.